# SSO Authentication: IDP in Java and SP in PHP

Tags: java, saml, opensaml, simplesamlphp

I have created SimpleSAMLphp to configure the Service Provider and OpenSAML in JAVA as IDP to send the assertion to SP. Now I'll login in my IDP server and through a link will come to SP server with SSO authentication but in my current scenario the request from IDP (at Java end) could not be connected with SP and I could not get the request on SP server. I have written code like this:

```
$config2 = SimpleSAML_Configuration::getInstance();
$asId = 'default-sp';
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple($asId);
$as->requireAuth();

if($as->isAuthenticated()){
print_r($as->getAttributes());
}
```

and at the IDP server, we have setup the XML assertion like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Destination="{Destination URL}" ID="pfx_0x834b6b3e7d22b4af67cd0ba03f609d8c" IssueInstant="2018-03-13T06:52:41Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml:Issuer>{URL of IDP}</saml:Issuer>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>pQ6y5qJUjSfi6b92hfsWanjQLp8=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>eVF5BoZ89bW0Lq19KZA3Txykl8nyWQg1LZVtXL20cSRYs8yurYqpcyH5a7nRzmYahQBcNHLrQ3Ym1jXwI3ZHZGE9tzxLNkt</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIIGQDCCBSigAwIBAgITGAAAAZ2HGmcpPW/rIgAAAAABnTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZMRIwEAYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYCYWUxFDASBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgRjb3JwMRgwFgYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYIZXRpc2FsYXQxEzARBgNVBAMTC</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
         <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
               <Modulus>mzwHw89DXYEJDhL/AeLwb0fHyrz0Vkd1tb5bkdbAZd4GKxBp6cQxNKB6SSR07EwniU1QeUYcdkypty7+/HWMFplabuq577</Modulus>
               <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
         </KeyValue>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </samlp:Status>
   <saml:Assertion xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="A_0x834b6b3e7d22b4af67cd0ba03f609d8c" IssueInstant="2018-03-13T06:52:41Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml:Issuer>{URL of IDP}</saml:Issuer>
      <saml:Subject>
         <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">test@test.com</saml:NameID>
         <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-03-14T06:52:41Z" Recipient="{SP URL}" />
         </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml:Subject>
      <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-03-13T06:52:41Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-03-14T06:52:41Z">
         <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience />
         </saml:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml:Conditions>
      <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-03-13T06:52:41Z" SessionIndex="_0x5291ba94c7b90fa1b3908cb5500a85f9" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2018-03-14T06:52:41Z">
         <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
         </saml:AuthnContext>
      </saml:AuthnStatement>
      <saml:AttributeStatement>
         <saml:Attribute Name="username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">takarimkhan</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CustomerAdmin</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="PartyID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">[4510988, 21378180, 13162764]</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test@test.com</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">TANAVAR KARIMKHAN</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="contactNumber" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">0501234567</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="channel" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">B2B</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
      </saml:AttributeStatement>
   </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Please let me know how can we connect with IDP and get all the information from Assertion?

Comment: OpenSAML isn't an IdP. Have you used actual IdP software such as the Shibboleth implementation from Internet2?

Comment: ... but it can be used to implement one. I think you have to to some general debugging. Begin with turning on all logs on the SP side and see if the Assertion gets there at all, and what it says about it.